# How to preview VIsualforce as it would look in Salesforce1?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I have a Visualforce page I'm working on. Just wanna preview it as it would look in Salesforce1 without adding any links or anything yet. It's just work in progress. How can I obtain a link for the Salesforce1 version? I already have a Chrome extension that changes my user agent so the site thinks I'm visiting from a mobile device.

Comment: in SF1 we don't have direct preview option. So the options you have is create a temporary tab or redirect it from some standard button.

Comment: Are you using this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce1-simulator/cknbjckicenodbiaejbmkjhldffonggp ?